# Getting minutes between different dates in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm trying to calculate the time between the dates , at the beginning the formula 
was working fine but I've noticed that it does not work when the date is different

For example , I have the following information on cell A1: 09/15/2016 10:00 AM
On Cell B2 I have: 09/16/2016 10:00 AM

The formula is just B2-A1 but instead of giving me a result of 24 hours is just giving me 0 . I believe the formula is not recognizing that these are 2 different days and is just doing 10-10

Any idea how to fix this ?

Comment: If the formula is `=B2-A1` it should return 1.  do you have a number format on the cell? If so, what is it?

Comment: What is the format of the cell containing the formula?  Excel stores date/times as days and fractions of a day since 1/1/1900.  If you have the cell formatted to show, for example, minutes:Seconds, it may show zero.  If you just want minutes, then multiply your result by 1440 (number of minutes in a day) and format the result as General.

Comment: If you want to show the time between two dates then use `[hh]:mm:ss` as your cell format.  The limit to this is 9999:59:59.

Comment: I've changed the format as you said and I'm still getting zero on the result

Cell A2 :  8/16/2016 10:00 AM
Cell B2:   8/16/2016 10:00 AM

Formula in Cell C2: =B2-A2

with General format = o
With [hh]:mm:ss = 0:00:00

Comment: Now you wrote `8/16/2016 10:00 AM` for both cells, the difference is really 0:00:00 then...

Comment: try set all cells into general format (`Ctrl + Shift + ~`) for checking, there should be a clear difference in the numbers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get the result 24 by setting a custom format of [h] (you will have to type it into the 'Type:' box) on cell C1 while using the formula =B1-A1

[Excel Reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HqRod.png)

['Format Cells' view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qUZR6.png)

The problem with just using =B1-A1 is that if either or both of those cells is not populated then you will get weird numbers in C1.  You may want to make C1 display as a blank cell unless both boxes are populated, try something like this =IF(OR(ISBLANK(A1),ISBLANK(B1)),"",B1-A1)

The reason for the weird numbers is that Excel calculates time based on a predefined decimal system that indexes time starting at like 1/1/1900 or something like that.  So when manipulating or calculating time, that is something that you always have to keep in the back of your mind.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Formation the destination cell to  will do but since you have date and time combined it will show as 1 calendar day difference 0 only means that 12 am after the 1 day difference, I know it does not make any sense but its Excel...

If I was you, on column A, I would add the date, and on Column B, the time.
then just work with the time, as both combined can be tricky

**Don't forget to format your cells!! (right click>Format Cells>Time>3/14/12 1:30 PM)**